# What would be the best way to click on this element?

Tags: c#, selenium

Quite new to C# and Selenium and I'm having issues clicking on the "automate test" area.

```
    <td _ngcontent-rur-c238="">
       <div _ngcontent-rur-c238="" class="left" style="width: 70%;">
           <div _ngcontent-rur-c238="" style="float: left;">
           <!---->
           <!---->
               <span _ngcontent-rur-c238="" class="s-truncate">Automate Test</span>
           </div>
```

This element is part of a table and is the only item i want to click. I have tried with linked text and with the xpath and always get the "unable to find element" error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would also like to add that the _ngcontent-rur-c238 or the class "s-truncate" is not unique

Comment: if it's yours product why not to add (maybe auto-generated) ids to all that table cells? In my opinion it's must-have policy for projects with UI tests.

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer your question. Automation with Selenium has many ways for things to fail. See [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405792/3092298).

Comment: @ba-a-aton you are correct, i have spoken with the developer team and they will be implementing ids to several parts of the website, but unfortunately cannot attend to it anytime soon. I managed to find a non optimal solution that will break if the table changes (anything is added for example). Does the job for now. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @GregBurghardt thank you, i will bookmark that and keep into consideration before posting again

Comment: @DjNewma The point of Greg's post was to have you fix THIS one AND all future questions. The rules apply to all posts, not just those after you learn the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the text "Automate Test" is unique.

Using XPath => the text equals "Automate Test":

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='s-truncate'][text()='Automate Test']");
```

Or XPath => the text contains "Automate Test"

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='s-truncate'][contains(text(),'Automate Test')]");
```